# openldap "no global superior knowledge"

Tags: openldap

When I:

```
ldapadd -f pop01.ldif -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=ldap,dc=beonegroup,dc=be" -w 1234
```

I get:

```
adding new entry "dc=ldap,dc=beonegroup,dc=org"
ldapadd: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
        additional info: no global superior knowledge
```

Here is my slapd.conf:

```
database    bdb
suffix      "dc=ldap,dc=beonegroup,dc=be"
rootdn      "cn=Manager,dc=ldap,dc=beonegroup,dc=be"
rootpw          1234
directory   /var/lib/ldap/beoneDirectory
index objectClass                       eq,pres
index ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname      eq,pres,sub
index uidNumber,gidNumber,loginShell    eq,pres
index uid,memberUid                     eq,pres,sub
index nisMapName,nisMapEntry            eq,pres,sub
```

And my file used to populate:

> ```
> [root@local beoneDirectory]# pwd
> /var/lib/ldap/beoneDirectory
> [root@local beoneDirectory]# cat pop01.ldif
> dn: dc=ldap,dc=beone,dc=org
> objectClass: top
> objectClass: dcObject
> objectClass: organization
> dc: beone
> o: beone
> description: ldap.beone.be
>
> dn: o=beone
> objectClass: top
> objectClass: organization
> o: beone
> description: Beone
>
> dn: cn=Manager,o=beone
> objectClass: organizationalRole
> cn: Manager
> description: LDAP Directory Administrator
>
> dn: ou=Employes,o=beone
> ou: Employes
> objectClass: top
> objectClass: organizationalUnit
> description: Employes beone
>
> dn: ou=Clients,o=beone
> ou: Clients
> objectClass: top
> objectClass: organizationalUnit
> description: Clients beone
>
> #1ere entrée
> dn: cn=Benoit Le,ou=Employes,o=beonegroup
> cn: Benoit Le
> objectClass: top
> objectClass: person
> objectClass: organizationalPerson
> objectClass: inetOrgPerson
> mail: benoit@beone.be
> givenname: Benoit
> sn: Lecomte
> ou: Employes
> street: 29 rue de cp
> l: jumet
> postalCode: 6040
> telephoneNumber: 04942311
> mobile: 01234345
>
> #2eme employé
> dn: cn=Matteo Di,ou=Employes,o=beonegroup
> cn: Matteo Di
> objectClass: top
> objectClass: person
> objectClass: organizationalPerson
> objectClass: inetOrgPerson
> mail: mat@beone.be
> ```

I know this is a slapd.conf related issue, openldap doesn't know where to insert my entries but I don't really see how to specify it

Answer (score 32):

Your database is named (has suffix):

```
dc=ldap,dc=beonegroup,dc=be
```

You are in the ldif trying to add stuff to

```
dn: dc=ldap,dc=beone,dc=org
```

This is somewhat equivalent of makeing a directory called `/something`, then trying to create the file `/some/file`. It won't work since the directory `/some` doesn't exist.

Remember LDAP data is organized in a hierarchical structure, i.e. the form of a tree like directories and files are. The word *superior* refers to the level above (closer to top), similar to *parent directory* (closer to root) in the filesystem example.

In the filesystem you would get the error message `/some/file: No such file or directory`

The LDAP error could probably have been worded better, but to fix this you have to either change the suffix in your slapd.conf or change the stuff you want to add. They have to match.

(Thanks to lilalinux for in the comments also specifying how to fix)

Comment: This answer tells us what is wrong, it doesn't explain how to fix it.

Comment: Either change the suffix in your slapd.conf or change the stuff you want to add. They have to match.

Comment: Knowing how something is wrong is 1000x more valuable than just knowing how to fix it in a single specific case. "plz just tell me what to copy-paste so I can fix" is the wrong attitude to have on this site, I think.

Answer (score 10):

The domain component structure what you have defined "dc=ldap,dc=beonegroup,dc=be" in not matching with your input entry in pop01.ldif first line.

Try to change the first line in your pop01.ldif from dc=org to dc=be and try again.