# ldapadd gives "no global superior knowledge" on default config

Tags: ldap, docker, openldap

### Background:

I'm installing a [Prosody](https://prosody.im/) XMPP server and [Kaiwa](http://getkaiwa.com/) webclient on a DigitalOcean droplet.

Kaiwa has a one-click deploy-to-DO-droplet tool using Docker that I tried first, but it didn't work - probably because I'm using the 512MB minimum DO VPS and it ran out of memory with half of the Docker images started.

I wiped all those images, made a 1GB swap file for my droplet and am now following (as suggested) the [Kaiwa GitHub README](https://github.com/digicoop/kaiwa-server#installation-with-docker) for "manual" install - which is essentially pulling and configuring four Docker images: `postgresql`, `slapd`, `kaiwa-server`, and `kaiwa`.  Setting up the PostgreSQL image went without a hitch, and I ran into trouble with the LDAP one.

### Problem:

Here are the instructions for configuring the LDAP Docker image:

```
$ docker pull nickstenning/slapd
$ docker run -d \
             --name ldap \
             -p 389:389 \
             -e LDAP_DOMAIN=myorga \
             -e LDAP_ORGANISATION=MyOrganisation \
             -e LDAP_ROOTPASS=mypassword \
             nickstenning/slapd
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digicoop/kaiwa-server/master/users.ldif
$ ldapadd -h localhost -x -D cn=admin,dc=myorga -w mypassword -f users.ldif
```

(I've omitted a number of `sed` commands used to replace sample data in [`users.ldif`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digicoop/kaiwa-server/master/users.ldif) with personal data; I get the same error with both datasets.)

After running the `ldapadd` command, I get this:

```
adding new entry "ou=users,dc=example.com"
ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
    additional info: no global superior knowledge
```

Experimenting shows that if I call `ldapadd` with user `user1` and password `user1pass`, or if I call it with user `admin` but with the wrong admin password, I get a different error:

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

I assume this means that the second, `docker run` command worked and my LDAP server recognizes that the admin user and password passed to `ldapadd` are correct, but for some reason I'm asking it to attach users to places that don't exist in the tree.

I've never used LDAP before and I'm probably making some silly mistake.  I've read this SO question ([openldap "no global superior knowledge"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168398/openldap-no-global-superior-knowledge)) and my problem is probably similar - but I wouldn't expect a typo to exist when I'm using the developers' default config file, and I haven't found one myself yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have named the root of your LDAP DIT as `dc=myorga`. So an entry that requires `ou=users,DC=example.com` isn't going to work. You'll have to change that accordingly.

Comment: That is indeed the case for the sample data here, but in my own data I had replaced `dc=myorga` with `dc=personaldoma.in`.  You did make me look closer there, though, and what eventually solved my problem was using the broken-up version: `dc=personaldoma,dc=in` instead.  I was surprised; I thought both styles were allowed.

Comment: Both styles are allowed, but they're not equivalent to each other, they're distinct.

Answer (score 0):

To me it was caused by spaces after the attribute values.

Comment: Could you add some detail, or example as to why this would be the case?